# How to suppress network configuration dialog in BartPE?

Tags: windows-xp, bartpe

Is there any way to suppress Network Configuration Dialog and have it set DHCP silently?
I am trying to build ISO image which doesn't need any user interaction and will run some actions from autoexec.bat (if that is possible).

Comment: Question:  Why are you still using BartPE?  Why don't you build a Windows PE disc?  You can even make a Windows 7 PE disc because the file system is still NTFS.

Comment: If I can create PXE bootable image with WinPE which will work silently then please post your answer with some details. My hardware is solely targeting to Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a Windows 7 PC to do these steps on, or install a trail version if need be.  If you have the correct drivers you will be able to access the file system and network from this environment.

Windows AIK download link
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753
Reference material:

instructions for making PE disc.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc709665%28v=WS.10%29.aspx

Options for autostart
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc766521%28v=WS.10%29.aspx

Location: %SYSTEMROOT%\System32
Edit the StartNet.cmd file add your stuff at the end.

**Briefly:**

Install Windows AIK see above

```
1. click Start, point to All Programs, point to Windows AIK, right- click Deployment Tools Command Prompt, and then select Run as administrator.
   Destination: Make a new temp folder and use that.
   We are going to make a folder named: c:\winpe_x86
2.  copype.cmd x86 <destination>
3.  copy c:\winpe_x86\winpe.wim c:\winpe_x86\ISO\sources\boot.wim
4.  copy "c:\program files\Windows AIK\Tools\x86\imagex.exe" c:\winpe_x86\iso\
5.  imagex /mountrw c:\winpe_x86\winpe.wim 1 c:\winpe_x86\mount
6.  Modify/Replace StartNet.cmd with your commands.
7.  peimg /prep c:\winpe_x86\mount\Windows
8.  imagex /unmount c:\winpe_x86\mount /commit
9.  dism /Mount-Wim /WimFile:c:\winpe_x86\winpe.wim /index:1 /MountDir:c:\winpe_x86\mount

10.  The drivers need to be uncompressed so the *.inf files are visible.
Download and extract Network and SATA/IDE drivers for devices that you need that are not built in.  These drivers are the most critical.
DISM.exe /Image:c:\winpe_x86\mount /Add-Driver /Driver:d:\Drivers\ /Recurse

11. dism /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:c:\winpe_x86\mount /commit
12. copy c:\winpe_x86\winpe.wim c:\winpe_x86\ISO\sources\boot.wim
13. oscdimg -n -bc:\winpe_x86\etfsboot.com c:\winpe_x86\ISO c:\winpe_x86\winpe_x86.iso
```

Now you should have a new ISO you can use just as you use the barpe ISO in your PXE.

Questions, just ask.